# Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{4}\right)$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\big(\frac{n\pi}{4}\big)$$ convergent?

I'm pretty sure it isn't due to the oscillatory nature of the sine function but I'm not sure how I would prove it. Would using the definition of convergence of a series work? (I.e saying that the sequence of partial sums cannot converge since you can consider two sub sequences that converge to different limits? Example $n=0$, 4, 8, 12,... converges to 0 and $n=2$, 6, 10, 14... converges to $\frac{1}{2}$). Any ideas?

Comment: The terms do not have limit $0$, so the series does not converge.

Comment: How exactly would you justify this I know it's obvious but how would you rigorously show it. Also out of interest would the method I suggested work?

Comment: It is the first result that is proved to you in any calculus course just after defining what is a series of real numbers. If $s_n$ is the sequence of partial sums ($s_n=a_0+..+a_n$), the sum converges to $S$ if and only if $s_n\to S$, hence $a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}\to (S-S)=0$.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that result I'm talking about the fact that the limit of $sin(x)$ does not equal zero.

Comment: If $n=8k+2$, then $\frac{\pi n}{4}=2k\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}$, and the sine of this is $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

If $\sum_n a_n$ converges, then $\lim_n a_n = 0$.

To prove this result, let $s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$ be the $n^{th}$ partial sum. Then $s_n \to s$ for some $s$. Thus, given $\epsilon>0$ we can find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|s_n-s| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ if $n > N$. Thus if $n>N$, then $|a_{n+1}|=|s_{n+1}-s_n| \leq |s_{n+1}-s|+|s-s_n| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon$. So $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: How exactly would you justify this I know it's obvious but how would you rigorously show it. Also out of interest would the method I suggested work?

Comment: There is a subsequence of $a_n$ such that $a_n = 1$ for $n=2+8k,\, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Ryan: This is part of the basics about numerical series.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: (An alternative attempt.) Partial sums are periodic, nonconstant,indeed. Just count them to $n=16$ to see the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

A variant: consider the associated complex series $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \mathrm e^{\tfrac{n\mathrm i\pi}4}$ (the O.P.'s series is its imaginary part).

It's a geometric series, and a partial sum is:
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \mathrm e^{\tfrac{n\mathrm i\pi}4}=\smash{\frac{1-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{(N+1)\mathrm i\pi}4}}{1-\mathrm e^{\tfrac{\mathrm i\pi}4}}}$$
These partial sums can't have a limit since $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{(N+1)\mathrm i\pi}4}$ is ($4$-)periodic.